# Weekly viral Spotify charts

Tags: charts, spotify

There used to be a website spotifycharts.com, which I loved.
I guess it was not an official Spotify site, but it seems that Spotify bought it, because it now redirects to charts.spotify.com.

I liked to keep track of weekly viral charts, that could be filtered by country.
Now in the charts.spotify.com I can only select daily viral songs for a country, there is no weekly viral chart.

Is it possible somehow to access weekly viral Spotify charts for individual countries?
Maybe there are other third party websites that calculate the charts?

Or we could use Spotify API to make something like that ourselves. But I don't know if we can filter the data from Spotify API by date. For example - is it possible to get a list of songs that were streamed in a specific country from 2022-06-06 to 2022-06-12, and have the number of times these songs were streamed in the specified country and how many times they were shared.